# Выбрать значения из базы данных, содержащие данную строку

Tags: python, sql, sqlite3

у меня есть база данных "users.db" , содержащая таблицу "users", записи в которой имеют следующую структуру:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу получить все записи, в которых передаваемая строка `str` входит в строку из колонки `user_name`:

```
str in user_name = True
```

Обращение к базе данных происходит посредством sqlite3. Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу это сделать)

Comment: [INSTR()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr)

Comment: Да вы просто издеваетесь, вы бы в гугле быстрее ответ нашли чем регались тут и писали вопрос. Вопрос гуглу: "sqlite3 запрос на выборку". В первых же ссылках есть все примеры и подключения к БД и примеры различных SQL запросов. Такое впечатление что вопросы пишут боты для наполнения форума контентом.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте оператор `like`:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name LIKE '%Петр%'
```

В запросе с `sqlite3` с переменной это выглядит так (тут `%` это спецсимвол для `like`, чтобы поиск был в любой части текста)

```py
text = '%Петр%'
connect.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name LIKE ?", [text]).fetchall()
```

С sqlite 3.7.15 можно использовать функцию [instr](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr) (тут уже не нужно будет добавлять `%`, чтобы найти внутри строки, в отличии от `like`):

```py
text = 'Петр'
connect.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE instr(user_name, ?) > 0", [text]).fetchall()
```

Comment: ... и не забыть про квотирование спецсимволов `%` и `_`...

Comment: @Akina, при в примере с кодом используется связывание параметров через `?`, поэтому не нужно беспокоиться о экранировании `text`

Comment: Но литерал-то влетит в шаблон, и будет там использован как знак подстановки. Я ж не предлагаю поставить кавычки вокруг знака вопроса...

Comment: @Akina, понял... wildcard спецсимволы не экранируются

Comment: Угу... не, понятно, что в данном конкретном случае ждать знаков подстановки как литер глупо - всё же ФИО... но я бы оговорил как раз обратный случай - когда в строке поиска используется именно знак подстановки, т.е. вводимая юзером строка выглядит как `Влад%Петр` - т.е. он хочет сразу, одним махом, сыскать и Владимира Петрова, и Владислава Петренко...

Comment: @Akina, думаю, лучше дать пользователю из кода добавлять спецсимволы. Кст, спасибо, за комментарий, не знал :)